# Symfony4: How to transfer data to a new (logged in) session? e.g. shopping cart data

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to allow guest visotors to store items in a shopping cart.

That cart should be taken into the new session, if that guest logs into an existing account.

Currently I save a session ID alongside cart data in my DB.
But as soon as a user logs into their account, the session ID is changed, so I don't have a way of moving the data from one session to the next.

What is the best way to (selectively) move data into a new session?

Comment: If you want a cheep solution. Store the user's cart in the browser's localStorage. On logging check if there are items in the localStorage and update the DB.

Comment: How about not saving sessionId in cart data but creating another unique key and using it in session and cart db together?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the documentation.

There are many type of session usage 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html